# 'node with name "rabbit" is already running on host' even after killing the processes

Tags: python, django, windows, rabbitmq, clone

Whenever I try to run a rabbit server, it meets me with this error:

```
ERROR: node with name "rabbit" is already running on host "DESKTOP-BKRTA3R"
```

I've read that I should kill the processes of rabbit by using

```
rabbitmqctl stop
```

But I still get the error, What else can I do
I am on windows 10

Here is my full error

```
2022-11-11 16:46:03.015000-08:00 [error] <0.131.0>
2022-11-11 16:46:03.015000-08:00 [error] <0.131.0> BOOT FAILED
2022-11-11 16:46:03.015000-08:00 [error] <0.131.0> ===========
2022-11-11 16:46:03.015000-08:00 [error] <0.131.0> ERROR: node with name "rabbit" is already 
running on host "DESKTOP-BKRTA3R"
2022-11-11 16:46:03.015000-08:00 [error] <0.131.0>
BOOT FAILED
===========
ERROR: node with name "rabbit" is already running on host "DESKTOP-BKRTA3R"

2022-11-11 16:46:04.017000-08:00 [error] <0.131.0>     supervisor: {local,rabbit_prelaunch_sup}
2022-11-11 16:46:04.017000-08:00 [error] <0.131.0>     errorContext: start_error
2022-11-11 16:46:04.017000-08:00 [error] <0.131.0>     reason: {duplicate_node_name,"rabbit","DESKTOP-BKRTA3R"}
2022-11-11 16:46:04.017000-08:00 [error] <0.131.0>     offender: [{pid,undefined},
2022-11-11 16:46:04.017000-08:00 [error] <0.131.0>                {id,prelaunch},
2022-11-11 16:46:04.017000-08:00 [error] <0.131.0>                {mfargs,{rabbit_prelaunch,run_prelaunch_first_phase,[]}},
2022-11-11 16:46:04.017000-08:00 [error] <0.131.0>                {restart_type,transient},
2022-11-11 16:46:04.017000-08:00 [error] <0.131.0>                {significant,false},
2022-11-11 16:46:04.017000-08:00 [error] <0.131.0>                {shutdown,5000},
2022-11-11 16:46:04.017000-08:00 [error] <0.131.0>                {child_type,worker}]
2022-11-11 16:46:04.017000-08:00 [error] <0.131.0>
2022-11-11 16:46:04.017000-08:00 [error] <0.129.0>   crasher:
2022-11-11 16:46:04.017000-08:00 [error] <0.129.0>     initial call: application_master:init/4
2022-11-11 16:46:04.017000-08:00 [error] <0.129.0>     pid: <0.129.0>
2022-11-11 16:46:04.017000-08:00 [error] <0.129.0>     registered_name: []
2022-11-11 16:46:04.017000-08:00 [error] <0.129.0>     exception exit: {{shutdown,
2022-11-11 16:46:04.017000-08:00 [error] <0.129.0>                          {failed_to_start_child,prelaunch,
2022-11-11 16:46:04.017000-08:00 [error] <0.129.0>                              {duplicate_node_name,"rabbit",
2022-11-11 16:46:04.017000-08:00 [error] <0.129.0>                                  "DESKTOP-BKRTA3R"}}},
2022-11-11 16:46:04.017000-08:00 [error] <0.129.0>                      {rabbit_prelaunch_app,start,[normal,[]]}}
2022-11-11 16:46:04.017000-08:00 [error] <0.129.0>       in function  application_master:init/4 (application_master.erl, line 142)
2022-11-11 16:46:04.017000-08:00 [error] <0.129.0>     ancestors: [<0.128.0>]
2022-11-11 16:46:04.017000-08:00 [error] <0.129.0>     message_queue_len: 1
2022-11-11 16:46:04.017000-08:00 [error] <0.129.0>     messages: [{'EXIT',<0.130.0>,normal}]
2022-11-11 16:46:04.017000-08:00 [error] <0.129.0>     links: [<0.128.0>,<0.44.0>]
2022-11-11 16:46:04.017000-08:00 [error] <0.129.0>     dictionary: []
2022-11-11 16:46:04.017000-08:00 [error] <0.129.0>     trap_exit: true
2022-11-11 16:46:04.017000-08:00 [error] <0.129.0>     status: running
2022-11-11 16:46:04.017000-08:00 [error] <0.129.0>     heap_size: 376
2022-11-11 16:46:04.017000-08:00 [error] <0.129.0>     stack_size: 28
2022-11-11 16:46:04.017000-08:00 [error] <0.129.0>     reductions: 167
2022-11-11 16:46:04.017000-08:00 [error] <0.129.0>   neighbours:
2022-11-11 16:46:04.017000-08:00 [error] <0.129.0>
2022-11-11 16:46:04.043000-08:00 [notice] <0.44.0> Application rabbitmq_prelaunch exited with reason: {{shutdown,{failed_to_start_child,prelaunch,{duplicate_node_name,"rabbit","DESKTOP-BKRTA3R"}}},{rabbit_prelaunch_app,start,[normal,[]]}}
{"Kernel pid terminated",application_controller,"{application_start_failure,rabbitmq_prelaunch,{{shutdown,{failed_to_start_child,prelaunch,{duplicate_node_name,\"rabbit\",\"DESKTOP-BKRTA3R\"}}},{rabbit_prelaunch_app,start,[normal,[]]}}}"}
Kernel pid terminated (application_controller) ({application_start_failure,rabbitmq_prelaunch,{{shutdown,{failed_to_start_child,prelaunch,{duplicate_node_name,"rabbit","DESKTOP-BKRTA3R"}}},{rabbit_prelaunch_app,start,[normal,[]]}}})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the process with a PID and using `taskkill`.

```
set /p pid=<%~dp0rabbitmq.pid
taskkill /F /PID %pid%
del /F /Q %~dp0rabbitmq.pid
```

Comment: My system can't find the file in the first command